# Facebook OAuth after get my access token - C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, facebook-oauth

I need some help.
I don't no what to do after the user allows my application. On my pageLoad I verify if the URL has code(generated by Facebook) and redirect again with the string code to get the access token.
Facebook redirect again with the access token and now I have the token.

What is the next step?

> ...on pageload...
>   ..........................
>   if (Request.QueryString["code"] != null && !Page.IsPostBack)
>   {
>       string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
>       string urlFinal = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" +
>                              "client_id=" + appID +
>                              "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURL +
>                              "&client_secret=" + appSecret +
>                              "&code=" + code;
>       Response.Redirect(urlFinal);
>   }
>   else if (Request.QueryString["access_token"] != null)
>       string token = Request.QueryString["access_token"];
>       //AND NOW??

Answer (score 1):

> and redirect again with the string code to get the access token.

**Don’t** *redirect* to that address – it contains your app secret!

You should make a *server-side* call to that endpoint instead – as described in the authentication docs.

> What is the next step?

That highly depends on what you want to do, don’t you think?

Comment: How I do a server-side call? Can you send me the link to "atuthentication docs"?

Comment: I don't understand the step 4. can you show me an example code?

Comment: If you don’t know how to make an HTTP request in the languages you’re using, please go google it.

Comment: I recive always this exception: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. it happens when I'm using the oAuthFacebook class, in the method WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)

Comment: Make a debug output of the actual request URL being used, and see what it says when you copy&paste it into your browser.

Comment: I give up. Now i'm trying authentication in the client side, he logs in and show the user name.. but how I alert my server that he made the login by facebook?